# Shiny InfoBox Width not Applying

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to get two shiny InfoBox's to fit alongside each other, between them taking the full width within a fluid row.  To do this, I'm specifying width = 6, i.e. half of the bootstrap 12.

However, the width parameter is having no effect on the Div Class which comes up as col-sm-4 (#shiny-html-output col-sm-4)regardless.  As a result, the two boxes take up 2/3's of the with (4+4 twelfths).

As a side question, I'd also like to be able to specify the skin colour directly, not just as yellow, which is the closest I can get to orange from the available skin colours.  I suspect I need to override with CSS.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
dashboard_colour <- "orange"

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Overview", tabName = "overview", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "overview",
                h2("Overview"),
                fluidRow(
                    infoBoxOutput("boxLeft"),
                    infoBoxOutput("boxRight")
                )
        )
    )
)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    skin = "yellow",
    dashboardHeader(title = "Orange Dashboard"),
    sidebar,
    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$boxLeft <- renderValueBox({
        infoBox(
            123, "No on Left", 
            icon = icon("arrow-alt-circle-left", class = "infoIcon"),
            color = dashboard_colour,
            width = 6
        )
    })
    output$boxRight <- renderValueBox({
        infoBox(
            456, "No on Right", 
            icon = icon("arrow-alt-circle-right", class = "infoIcon"),
            color = dashboard_colour,
            width = 6
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the `infoBoxOutput` a width of 6 does the job:

```
    fluidRow(
              infoBoxOutput("boxLeft", width = 6),
              infoBoxOutput("boxRight", width = 6)
            )
```